# I want to give cornerRadius to an arc made of UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cornerradius

I made an arc using the UIBezierPath and I'm going to give it cornerRadius
Here's my code

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let path = UIBezierPath(
    arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY),
    radius: rect.midX - 16 - 20,
    startAngle: .pi,
    endAngle: 2 * .pi,
    clockwise: true
    )
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 40
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineCap = .round

layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07x9h.jpg)
This is my result
cornerRadius was applied throughout the lineWidth
But what I want is to apply about 5 on the corner
What shoud I do?
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkYGl.jpg)

Comment: You need a little a math (geometry). You need instead do draw that form, by calculating each point, then connect them with an arc line.

Comment: You can simply add two rectangles at each side rounding both lower corners

Comment: Do you want to ***add*** rounded corners (pretty easy / straightforward)? Or, do you want to ***clip*** rounded corners (not so easy)? See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApXcE.png